# Is there a way to use \p{Punct}\p{Lower}\p{Upper} and in a regex(java), but without the "." character?

Tags: java, regex

I need to take out all the characters of a string that are not numbers.

Comment: post some valid examples along with expected output.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [Character Class Intersection](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclassintersect.html) like `[\p{Punct}\p{Lower}\p{Upper}&&[^.]]`

But why not just use

```
[^\d.]+
```

As Java String `"[^\\d.]+"`

This would match one or more characters, that are not `\d` a digit or the `.` period.

Comment: You're welcome @MarcoKoblinsky

Comment: `(?![.])[\p{Punct}\p{Lower}\p{Upper}]`

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using `\\d+` then (it's consecutive digits), and a capture group. Something like

```
String str = "";
str = str.replaceAll("(\\d+\\.\\d+)", "$1");
```